# Why is a Feistel network not a type of substitution-permutation network?

Tags: substitution-cipher, permutation, feistel-network

I understand what substitution-permutation networks look like. I understand what Feistel networks and Feistel-like networks look like. A Feistel network or a Feistel-like network features substitution and permutations, so why is it considered distinct from an SP-network?

Comment: Your question is not clear. A Feistel network could contain an SPN in its $f$ function but that is distinctly different from SPN itself

Answer (score 4):

In the substitution step of a typical Substitution-Permutation Network (e.g. in [AES SubBytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#The_SubBytes_step)), the ***whole*** state is broken in parts and each part substituted. That's not the case in (the core of) a Feistel cipher, where at each step/round some sizable part of the state is bound to remain unchanged (in order that each step be reversible).